# key only call once while down in python

Tags: python, event-handling, tkinter, key

I am trying to make a game in python using tkinter ( i don't really want to learn pygame stuff ) and i am make an input processor using keys. I am trying to differenciate between a key down and a key press

when a key down is called constantly while its pressed and a key press only calls it onces until it is released and pressed again.

```
numKeys = 7
UP = 0
LEFT = 1
DOWN = 2
RIGHT = 3
ENTER = 4
ESCAPE = 5
SPACE = 6

keys = [False] * numKeys 
keyRegister = 0
keyFlag = False

def keyDown(event): 
    if event.keysym == "Up": 
        setKey(UP, True) 
    if event.keysym == "Left": 
        setKey(LEFT, True) 
    if event.keysym == "Down": 
        setKey(DOWN, True) 
    if event.keysym == "Right": 
        setKey(RIGHT, True) 
    if event.keysym == "Enter": 
        setKey(ENTER, True) 
    if event.keysym == "Escape": 
        setKey(ESCAPE, True) 
    if event.keysym == "space": 
        setKey(SPACE, True) 

    if keyRegister != 0: 
        keyFlag = True
    keyRegister += 1 


def keyUp(event): 
    if event.keysym == "Up": 
        setKey(UP, False) 
    if event.keysym == "Left": 
        setKey(LEFT, False) 
    if event.keysym == "Down": 
        setKey(DOWN, False) 
    if event.keysym == "Right": 
        setKey(RIGHT, False) 
    if event.keysym == "Enter": 
        setKey(ENTER, False) 
    if event.keysym == "Escape": 
        setKey(ESCAPE, False) 
    if event.keysym == "space": 
        setKey(SPACE, False) 

    keyRegister = 0
    keyFlag = False

def update(): 



def setKey(k,b): 
    keys[k] = b 


def isDown(k): 
    return keys[k] 

def isPressed(k): 
    if keyFlag == False: 
        return keys[k]
```

i also have my main file which if you look at the render func. is where im putting the input parts.

```
class main: 

    def __init__(self): 

        self.root = Tk() 
        root = self.root 
        self.root.title("Asteroids") 

        self.width = 500
        self.height = 400 

        root.resizable(width = False, height = False) 

        self.screen = Canvas( root,width = 500, height = 400, background = "black") 
        self.screen.pack() 

        root.after(200, self.render) 
        root.bind("<Key>", GameKeys.keyDown) 
        root.bind("<KeyRelease>", GameKeys.keyUp) 
        root.mainloop() 

    def render(self): 

        while True: 
            self.screen.delete("all") 

            if GameKeys.isPressed(GameKeys.SPACE): 
                print("SPACE") 

            self.screen.update() 
            #        GameKeys.update() 

            time.sleep(0.01)     



Game = main()
```

So i cant get it to do the "isPressed" function properly. Does anyone know a way about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you have an infinte, sleeping loop that never gives tkinter the chance to process any events. The event loop must be allowed to run so that events can be processed.

As a good general guideline, you should:

1. never call sleep in the main thread of a GUI
2. never put an infinite loop in the main thread of a GUI

You can solve both of these problems by using `after` to handle screen redraws:

```
def render(self):
    self.screen.delete("all")
    if GameKeys.isPressed(GameKeys.SPACE):
        print("SPACE")
    self.screen.update()
    self.after(100, self.render)
```